# Pointer Meta Information

Tags: c, memory

An interesting feature of `realloc()` is that it somehow knows how long your data is when it is copying or extending your allocated memory.

I read that what happens is that behind the scenes there is some meta information stored about a pointer (which contains it's allocated memory size), usually immediately before the address the pointer is pointing at (but of course, subject to implementation).

So my question is, if there is such data stored why isn't it exposed via an API, so things like the C string for example, won't have to look for a `\0` to know where the end of a string is.

There could be hundreds of other uses as well.

Comment: @JohnHascall but somehow `realloc()` also does `free()` which needs to know....

Comment: @ itay -- not necessary always in case of _strings_. I may very well allocate 128 bytes just to store "Sourav". In that case, the _hypothetical_ API would convey misleading info.

Comment: This may very well be compiler specific. I cannot recall that the C specification mentions anything about it.

Comment: ``Realloc`` is cookie and chokolade and cream all in one (``malloc``, ``free``, ``realloc``) and as such bad for your health. Just saying: realloc is a shiny example on how not to define a function.

Comment: You want the reallocation (and dealocation) to take place within `O(1)` operations (constant time complexity, regardless of the size of the allocated memory segment), and that is simply not possible when using the `\0` method.

Comment: free() also knows how much memory you allocated.  Sure, your memory allocator simply keeps track of the size by allocating a bit more.

Comment: @BitTickler and why's so? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @SouravGhosh There are different forms of arguments to a function. Simple values used for computation and the other form are also called "control variables", i.e. variables which have an impact on *what* a function does. Those "control variables" are a big no-no. To make this point more obvious, consider a function like ``void foo( int control, float x, float y);`` The control parameter would typically be used in a switch case statement in the implementation and contain various different behaviors. This is bad practice. ``realloc`` is even worse than foo because it is not even obvious.

Comment: @BitTickler I see, interesting. I used to think the opposite. Can you possibly share/link some article where i can dig more on this? Thanks for the info. :-)

Comment: For this and many more goodies, a copy of the book: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?WritingSolidCode is highly recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said yourself, it's subject to the implementation of the standard libraries' memory manager.

C doesn't have a standard for this type of functionality, probably because generally speaking C was designed to be simple (but also provide a lot of capabilities).

With that said, there isn't really much use for this type of functionality outside of features for debugging memory allocation.

Some compilers [do provide this type of functionality](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1666sb98.aspx) ([specifically memory block size](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swddftz0.aspx)), but it's made pretty clear that it's only for the purpose of debugging.

It's not uncommon to write your own memory manager, allowing you to have full control over allocations, and even make assumptions for other library components. As you mentioned, your implementation can store the size of an allocation somewhere in a header, and a string implementation can reference that value rather than walking the bytes for `\0` termination.

Answer (score 2):

This information is not always accurate.
On Windows, the size is rounded up to a multiple of at least 8.
`realloc` does fine with this because it cares only about the allocated size, but you won't get the requested size.

Comment: That is probably the precise reason why this meta info is not exposed. For some forms of implementations it would imply an extra burden.

Comment: The information is *accurate*; it accurately reflects whatever the implementation needs for its own purposes. It just doesn't necessarily store the requested size.

Answer (score 1):

Here it's worth understanding how allocators work a bit. For example, if you take a buddy allocator, it allocates chunks in predetermined sizes. For simplicity, let's say powers of 2 (real world allocators usually use tighter sizes).

In this kind of simplified case, if you call `malloc` and request 19 bytes of memory for your personal use, then the allocator is actually going to give you a 32-byte chunk worth of memory. It doesn't care that it gave you more than you needed, as that still satisfies your basic request by giving you something as large or larger than what you needed.

These chunk sizes are usually stored somewhere, somehow, for a general-purpose allocator that can handle variable-sized requests to be able to free chunks and do things like merge free chunks together and split them apart. Yet they're identifying the *chunk size*, not the size of your request. So you can't use that chunk size to see where a string should end, e.g., since according to you, you wanted one with 19 bytes, not 32 bytes.

`realloc` also doesn't care about your requested 19-byte size. It's working at the level of bits and bytes, and so it copies the whole chunk's worth of memory to a new, larger chunk if it has to.

So these kinds of chunk sizes generally aren't useful for implementing things like data structures. For these, you want to be working at the data size proportional to the amount of memory you requested which is something many allocators don't even bother to store (they don't need to in order to work given their efficiency needs). So it's often up to you to keep track of that size which is in tune with the logic of your software in some form (a sentinel like a null terminator is one form).

As for why querying these sizes is not available in the standard, it's probably because the need to know it would be a rather obscure, low-level kind of need given that it has nothing to do with the amount of memory you actually requested to work with. I have often wished for it for some very low-level debugging needs, but there are platform/compiler-specific alternatives that I have used instead, and I found they weren't quite as handy as I thought they would be (even for just low-level debugging).

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> if there is such data stored why isn't it exposed via an API, so things like the C string for example, won't have to look for a \0 to know where the end of a string is.

You can allocate enough memory with the ability to hold 100 characters but you may use that memory to hold a string that is only 5 characters long. If you relied on the pointer metadata, you will get the wrong result.

```
char* cp = malloc(100);
strcpy(cp, "hello");
```

The second reason you would need the terminating null character is when you use stack memory to create a string.

```
char str[100] = "hello";
```

Without the terminating null character, you won't be able determine the length of the string held in `str`.

You said:

> There could be hundreds of other uses as well.

I don't have a good response to that other than to say that custom memory allocators often provide access to the metadata. The reason for not including such APIs in the standard library is not obvious to me.

Comment: in this regard, I did [beat you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30516469/pointer-meta-information#comment49108294_30516469) by +/- 20 second. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh, indeed.

Comment: with all due respect sir, I think OP has no objction regarding the null-termination style itself, rather he wants to _cut-down_ the traversing time to find the null-termination. Can you shed some light on that aspect?

Comment: @SouravGhosh, the OP's question includeds *so things like the C string for example, won't have to look for a \0 to know where the end of a string is.* I am not seeing in the OP's question what you are seeing.

Comment: Absolutely, but IMHO OP said that as _one_ possible example (a poor one, maybe). I was just looking for more info to justify (or deny) _"hundreds of other uses as well"_.You're very right. though, as you can see, I agreed with you in first place.